# Multiple Yields From A Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, ruby-on-rails-4, partial, yield

I have a partial that supports a title value and either a subtitle value or a block:

```
<header class="PrimaryHeader">
  <h1 class="Title"><%= title %></h1>
  <% if defined? subtitle %>
    <div class="Subtitle"><%= subtitle %></div>
  <% else %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

Which I render like this:

```
<%= render layout: 'shared/headers/primary_header', locals: {title: "Edit Gallery"} do %>
  <div class="special">Subtitle</div>
<% end %>
```

**How can I also support an optional block for the title?**

Basically the equivalent of:

```
<header class="PrimaryHeader">
  <% if defined? title %>
    <h1 class="Title"><%= title %></h1>
  <% else %>
    <%= yield  %>
  <% end %>
  <% if defined? subtitle %>
    <div class="Subtitle"><%= subtitle %></div>
  <% else %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using locals like that, I would probably use multiple yielding regions. You could accomplish this like:

```
<header class='PrimaryHeader'>
  <%= content_tag(:h1, yield :title, class: 'Title') if content_for?(:title) %>
  <%= content_tag(:h2, yield :subtitle, class: 'Subtitle') if content_for?(:subtitle) %>
  <%= yield %>
</header>
```